# How to calculate warning log count in each session?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, logging, spring-aop

I need to calculate warning logs count while processing a particular request.

Process : Transferring a project information from one database to another database.
while processing the transaction based on some other constrains we are writing warning,info and debug logs.

lets consider 2 or more users working on this process, at the end of the transaction i need to inform the user "**your process completed with log. please check the log.**" or i have to show the critical logs to user.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Log4mongo for Java](http://log4mongo.org/display/PUB/Log4mongo+for+Java) to log your info into a mongodb, including user id, and query it when your process ends, getting the statistics you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there any other way to salve my problem . i don't want to write log into db and this will cause the performance in a bit.